# How to show a different view page for a same tab bar item?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a `UITabBarController` in a storyboard.
Three different `UIViewController`s are manually segued to each of tab bar item.
What I want is direct to a different view controller for one tab bar item.

For example, I have a myProfile tab bar item at index 2 and I would like to show login page for unregistered user, profile page for a normal user, and a profile page with additional functions for an admin user.

I would like to set the third tab bar item to direct either login_view(second right) or profile_view(the most right) depending on a condition. How should i do this?

[my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7prbY.png)

Comment: I am not sure about using the storyboard, but you can adjust UITabBarController's methods. That is, you can have functions for the tab bar with decision logic. It might be easier to have a UIViewController that is the whole of login/profile logic and will load the profile view if logged in or the login view if not logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new class and extends it of UITabBarController, and change the viewController's array with the ViewController that you want to set at the position if the user is logged or not. For Example

```
import UIKit
```

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

`var isLogged = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTabBar()
}

func configureTabBar() {
    if(isLogged) {
        self.viewControllers?[1] = ProfileViewController()

    }
}`

}

Setting the ProfileViewController at the position when you have the Login Page (1 on this case). After that, we need to set our custom UITabBarController on the storyboard :

1. Select the Tab Bar View Controller
2. Go to the Identity Inspector (On the Right side)
3. Set our custom TabBarViewController, you can see it on the next image link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOuP3.png